# What is the time complexity of the Linear Search c code that i have written below? is my code good or bad?

Tags: c, algorithm

//Linear search

```
#include<stdio.h>


void main()

{

    int a[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    int key;
    int v;
    printf("Insert the number you want to find in the list::\n");
    scanf("%d",&v);




    for(int i=0;i<=10;i++)
    {
        if(a[i]==v){
            key=i;
       break;
        }else{
          key=-1;
        }
    }  

      if(key>=0){
          printf("Number found at possition %d\n\n\n",key);
    }
    else{
        printf("Sorry Not found in the list\n\n\n");
    }

    printf("A programme by Soumya Darshan Rauth");

}
```

Comment: The test in your `for` loop has a bug. The array has 10 elements so the valid indices are 0..9. Your test will go one past the end of the array.

Comment: your linear search code has linear time aka O(n)

Answer (score 1):

Your program runs in linear time and is good for arrays which are small. For arbitrary input, your program is optimal. Though I don't think you need to set key=-1 every time you don't find your required value.

`key = -1;
for(int i=0;i<=10;i++)
    {
        if(a[i]==v){
            key=i;
       break;
        }
    }`

Even this will work just fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot Neo. Can you send me the code for arbitrary input that works in linear time?????

Comment: Your program will work for arbitrary input in linear time! I don't need to send you any code. 

You just have to find a way to input an arbitrary set of numbers to search from.. And it is probably a good exercise for you to work that out. If you face issues, stackoverflow has some excellent coders who will always be glad to help you out, if you show that you made an effort. :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, a linear search has linear time complexity, O(n), but with a fixed sized array like yours one [could say](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Constant_time) that it has constant time complexity, O(1).

Answer (score 1):

As everyone has said, it is O(n), but a sorted array can be searched in O(log2(n)) so it is not algorithmically the best that can be done

Also, on the C, it is fragile. It doesn't work for 10 numbers, and would fail for any other number of numbers than 11.

Usually we either have a name which is the actual number of elements in the array (I'll use old-style C which will work on anything:

```
void main()
{
#define MAX_A (10)
    int a[MAX_A]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
       // deleted some stuff

    for(int i=0; i<MAX_A; i++)
    {
        if(a[i]==v){
            key=i;
            break;
        }else{
            key=-1;
        }
    }
```

or we calculate the correct size of the array with this slightly strange `sizeof` calculation

```
void main()
{
    int a[MAX_A]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
       // deleted some stuff

    for(int i=0; i<sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]); i++)
    {
        if(a[i]==v){
            key=i;
            break;
        }else{
            key=-1;
        }
    }
```

which is always the size of the array.

You could write a more direct loop, e.g.

```
for (key=0; a[key]!= v && key<sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]); key++)
```

Then the test for a match changes to `key < sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])`

Answer (score 0):

Everytime the value is not found within your array, you manipulate variable 'key'.

An improvment you could do is initialize the key variable to -1 and remove the 'else' code block from within your loop.

Answer (score 0):

Linear search has always the complexity O(n).

In general, the main method should always have an integer as the return type (0 means success, everything else means that an error occured).
Furthermore, the main method accepts two parameters, the number of parameters and the parameters as a char array (int argc, char *argv[]).
If you don't need the parameters it's good style to write "void" between the parenthesis (int main(void)).
A break statement inside a for loop is generally considered as bad practice, because it's not obvious when/if the loop finishes. In your case a while loop would increase readability.
The while loop would look like this:

```
while (i < 10 && a[i] != v) {
    i++;
}
if (i >= 10) { ... } // not found
else { ... } // found at position i
```